Correct way to measure the uplift: S-learner or difference between real values and predictions of a model trained on non-treated samples
I want to measure the uplift associated with a change in a profile. For example, if I take the example of Airbnb, I'd like to measure if, when a host adds additional photos to his listing, an increase in conversion rate or page views is observed.
I am using an S-learner, where the treatment will be continuous (number of photos added to a profile). I can measure the uplift as the difference between the prediction with treatment and the predictions without treatment as described here.
But I can also train a model only on the samples without the treatment. Using that model, I can get counterfactuals of what would have happened without the treatment and measure the uplift on the treated.
Is there a way that is more reliable than the other to estimate a causal effect?
